# Проблема с библиотекой Clang в Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x, lib, clang

Пытаюсь заюзать clang в скрипте на питоне.
Делаю банальные операции:

```
from clang.cindex import Config, Index

path_to_lib = 'C://Python27//DLLs//libclang.dll'
Config.set_library_path(path_to_lib)
```

Дальше ещё код и в другой функции продолжаю работать с либой:

```
lib_clang_args = []
# Вот здесь падаю с ошибкой
cindex = Index.create()
```

> LibclangError: [Error 126] The specified module couldn't be found. To
>   provide a path to libclang use Config.set_library_path() or
>   Config.set_library_file().

Разрядность Питона, системы и clang одинаковы, 32 бита.
Путь до либы как только не прописывал - не помогло.
Подскажите, почему питон не видит либу и как это исправить?

**P.S.:** может с версией либы что-то не так? Уже кинул все файлы, какие надо по директориям внутри папки ***C://Python27***, а именно:

*C://Python27//Lib//cindex.py*
*C://Python27//Lib//cindex.pyc*
*C://Python27//Lib//enumerations.py*
*C://Python27//Lib//enumerations.pyc*
*C://Python27//libs//libclang.lib*
*C://Python27//DLLs//libclang.dll*

Тут вот ещё туториал, но он мне не помог решить проблему. Может кому-то будет полезно: [Parsing C++ in Python with Clang](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang)

Comment: os.path.exists(path_to_lib) проверьте, вдруг опечатались где-то

Comment: @FeroxTL, на консоль вывелось "True", значит, путь верный.